# Story Identification - Trilogy about VR and an old man who eats soap

Tags: story-identification, books

Alright, I read this trilogy almost a decade ago. And I'm pretty sure it wasn't new then. So could be from 90's or early 2000's

Basically, it was a trilogy that followed multiple people's stories. It heavily featured VR and Full Body VR Suits. There was an evil corporation whose HQ was a giant black tower in a lake (I think) and in the end the group of people who's stories all intertwined infiltrated it. Or something.

Few key things I remember, there was a young kid who lived near a weird old man. Kids parent's always told him to stay away, he didn't. And the old man ate soap.
There was a brother and a sister story arc, sister was older and looking after the brother.
And one of the books definitely had a gold cover.

I tried finding these books 5 years ago, and failed. Finally found them 2 years ago, and forgot their names AGAIN. Hopefully this time around I won't!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I post this question I manage to find the answer myself!

The series I was thinking of is called [Otherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland).

It's 4 books, not 3, and some of the minor details I didn't remember 100% accurately. But, that's the series!

Comment: Awesome! Try see if you can add in some additional details (e.g. plot points, snippets of text, etc.) that match your description above. This will help other users who may have forgotten a similar book confirm if this is the one they're looking for?

Comment: I had guessed it as well, Gold cover was the giveaway.

Comment: Close enough, Douglas Adams was famous for his Trilogy in four parts, or was it five?